# How to differentiate between userAgents?

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent

As the title says...

This is a userAgent in Safari (MacOS):
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.1 Safari/605.1.15`

and then here is the same in Chrome (MacOS):
`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36`

How am I supposed to tell which is which browser?

An escape route I found is `window.chrome` vs. `window.safari` as these are only defined in their own browser as the name suggests.

If anyone knows a somewhat more reliable or more detailed method to check these please let me know. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point isn't to differentiate by name, because new browsers can pop up any time. You're supposed to test functionality before using it, and to write most (if not all) of your page in a cross-browser way. You can use polyfills or libraries like jQuery and let them figure out how to fill in the blanks.

Comment: Unless, of course, you're a leech for an ad company, trying to steal as much data from users as possible and sell it to the highest bidder. In which case I'm also not inclined to help you.

Comment: No. It was for a parallax scroll event that did not work for Safari. But it turned out Safari does not understand nested css. Like: ```.hero { > img {} }```. While Chrome does understand it. But I figured out both understands this: ```.hero > img {}```

Comment: Ill read a bit on your suggestion to test functionality instead of just trying to figure out what browser we are in... Makes sense

Comment: This would be a case where the latter suggestion would be better -- use a polyfill for CSS, like SCSS or your favorite CSS extension library.

Comment: The site Im required to do is so small and simple I decided to go vanilla...

Comment: They're all pretty drop-in, you don't have to rearchitecture anything.